# Rails: list of users by most recent message (an index of conversations)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, messaging

Just like the left column of facebook's messaging interface, I want to list the users who have messaged or been messaged by the current_user, effectively making an index list of 'conversations'.

Items in this list could then be clicked to show a history of messages between the two users i.e. the actual conversation itself, which I already have working e.g.

```
Message.where("(sender_id = ? and user_id = ?) or (sender_id = ? and user_id = ?)",from_id, to_id, to_id, from_id)
```

What would the rails command look like to make this index of conversations? Something like `User.where has messaged current user` or `current_user.messages map unique users, order(message created_at)`?(excuse the convo-code)

Association schema:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd create association between User and Message and then do following

```
User.where(id: current_user.id).joins(:messages).order('messages.created_at DESC')
```

Comment: thanks for your reply - with this i'm getting 'undefined method `joins' for #<User:0x007fa16ae15808>' (using current_user)

Comment: (the association I have between the two is simply user has_many messages, and messages belong_to user)

Comment: The tricky part is how to model the association. I think you should override finder_sql to achive this.

Comment: hmm this is giving me lots of copies of the current_user... can we invert it to give the sender (via sender_id in message) of the message in each case?